# How to get IP address through VBA in UFT

Tags: vba, wmi

I am trying to get the Ipaddress through this below code in WIN10

I'm unable to iterate through the For loop as getting the below error.

> General run error.
>
> Line (4): "For Each IPConfig In IPConfigSet"

```vb
Set IPConfigSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
   ("select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE")

For Each IPConfig In IPConfigSet
  If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then
    For i = LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) To UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
      Debug.Print IPConfig.IPAddress(i)
    Next
  End If
Next
```

[image: Getting the Run error as below]

Comment: The method `Debug.Print` is not VBScript. It's likely VBA or VB.Net.

Comment: your code works perfectly in VBA. Explain better what your environment is.

Comment: Yes , can replace it with msgbox.. I want to know why it is failing at 'for each loop'

Comment: Is there any better way I can get the IP through vbscript?

Comment: if its VBscript, then adapt your question. This question describe only VBA in the title and tag which is false and misleading.